# Is my p2p server set up correctly? When will I see inbound connections on 8333?

Tags: bitcoind, testnet, windows, p2p, port

I've had a Windows host up at 23.23.246.5 for both Bitcoin and Namecoin and I'd like to make sure its configured correctly.

So far when I run a netstat I see the services below and a few things bother me:

- Why is Bitcoind listening on port 80?
- Why are there no inbound connections to Bitcoin (Prod or Test) or Namecoin?  When will I see them?
- Is the target host 92.243.23.21:6667 running IRC? If so what is that for?
- Are there any questionable connections here?

---

**More Information:**

---

*Bitcoin Launch Parameters*

- `bitcoind -debug -server -detachdb -printtodebugger -printtoconsole`

bitcoin.conf:

```
#noirc=0
server=0
rpcuser=Ulysseys
rpcpassword=YourSuperGreatPasswordNumber_DO_NOT_USE_THIS_OR_YOU_WILL_GET_ROBBED
#rpctimeout=30
rpcallowip=x.x.x.x  <-- my trusted IP set
rpcallowip=x.x.x.x  <-- my trusted IP set #2
rpcallowip=x.x.x.x  <-- my trusted IP set #3
rpcport=8332
#rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
#rpcssl=1
#rpcsslciphers=TLSv1+HIGH:!SSLv2:!aNULL:!eNULL:!AH:!3DES:@STRENGTH
#rpcsslcertificatechainfile=server.cert
#rpcsslprivatekeyfile=server.pem
#allowreceivebyip=1
```

---

*Namecoin Launch Parameters*

- `namecoind -debug -server -detachdb -printtodebugger -printtoconsole`

bitcoin.conf

```
server=1
rpcuser=asdf
rpcpassword=asdf
#rpctimeout=30
#rpcport=8336
#rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
#rpcssl=1
```

---

*Bitcoin Testnet Launch Parameters*

- `bitcoind -debug -server -detachdb -printtodebugger -printtoconsole -testnet -rpcport=18332`

NOTE: No bitcoin.conf is present in `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\testnet3` directory  assuming it is using `\..` parent directory

**Output**

```
C:\Users\Administrator>netstat   -a -n -b -s

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8332           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2624
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8333           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2624
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8334           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2928
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8336           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2928
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:18332          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2660
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:18333          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2660
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:49163    92.243.23.21:6667      ESTABLISHED     2660
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:49164    69.64.46.74:18333      ESTABLISHED     2660
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:49167    96.241.176.56:18333    ESTABLISHED     2660
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:49170    94.23.34.31:18333      ESTABLISHED     2660
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:49181    97.107.137.243:8334    ESTABLISHED     2928
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:49182    46.254.14.136:8334     ESTABLISHED     2928
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:49183    176.36.33.121:8334     ESTABLISHED     2928
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:49186    12.23.127.175:8334     ESTABLISHED     2928
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:49193    176.31.128.16:8334     ESTABLISHED     2928
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:49194    96.127.133.36:8334     ESTABLISHED     2928
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:49220    54.243.38.85:18333     ESTABLISHED     2660
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:49304    178.63.48.141:18333    ESTABLISHED     2660
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:50504    193.107.204.81:6667    ESTABLISHED     2928
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:53098    173.208.219.162:18333  ESTABLISHED     2660
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:53537    99.230.227.73:8333     ESTABLISHED     2624
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:55713    94.236.165.24:8333     ESTABLISHED     2624
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:55716    74.196.224.251:8333    ESTABLISHED     2624
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:56470    195.182.5.221:8334     ESTABLISHED     2928
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:57000    96.60.218.202:8333     ESTABLISHED     2624
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:57083    91.121.174.223:8334    ESTABLISHED     2928
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:59585    173.167.113.73:8333    ESTABLISHED     2624
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:60574    77.232.139.69:8333     ESTABLISHED     2624
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:63469    89.79.247.234:8333     ESTABLISHED     2624
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    10.193.55.114:63916    92.241.227.145:8333    ESTABLISHED     2624
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    [::]:8332              [::]:0                 LISTENING       2624
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    [::]:8333              [::]:0                 LISTENING       2624
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    [::]:18332             [::]:0                 LISTENING       2660
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    [::]:18333             [::]:0                 LISTENING       2660
 [bitcoind.exe]
```

Answer (score 1):

Quickly checking with telnet says you're all set up:

```
$ telnet 23.23.246.5 8333
Trying 23.23.246.5...
Connected to 23.23.246.5.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

Next checking if you appear in sipa's DNS Seed:

```
$ curl -s http://bitcoin.sipa.be/seeds.txt | grep 23.23.246.5
23.23.246.5:8333        100.00% 100.00% 100.00% 94.46%  51.36%  215073  60002 "/Satoshi:0.7.1/"
```

Since Sipa checks the version you can be sure that your node responds correctly to handshake requests, i.e., connections can be established. The same goes for bitcoin testnet.

Bitcoind is not listening on port 80. That's the HTTP port, and from the banner it appears that it is an IIS7 web server running on that port:

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

As for `92.243.23.21`, that is indeed an IRC server (part of LFnet) which is used by bitcoind to bootstrap its contact with the P2P network. `bitcoind` will connect to the server and join the channel #bitcoin. The usernames of participants in that channel are encoded IP addresses that bitcoind will then attempt to contact. So nothing to bother.

Finally the connections all seem to check out. They are all outgoing connections to the P2P network. They boil down to:

- 2 6667 outgoing to the IRC bootstrapping servers (giraffe.heliacal.net and irc.lfnet.org)
- 8 8333 outgoing to other bitcoin nodes
- 8 8334 outgoing to other namecoin nodes
- 6 18333 outgoing to bitcoin (testnet)

Currently I am unable to connect to port 8334 which would indicate that your `namecoin` is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Comment with the command lines you used to launch `bitcoind` and `namecoind` and I might be able to provide a better answer.

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8332           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8333           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8334           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8336           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [namecoind.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:18332          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:18333          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [wininit.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  eventlog
 [services.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49157          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [svchost.exe]

<snip>

 TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    [::]:8333              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    [::]:18332             [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [bitcoind.exe]
  TCP    [::]:18333             [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [bitcoind.exe]
```

I snipped out the outbound connections so we can focus on the listening sockets.

I'm making some assumptions:

- You're either running several copies of the daemons or you're listening on multiple ports. IIRC, 8333 is the sync port and 8332 is the RPC port for `bitcoind`, 8336 and 8334, respectively, for `namedcoind`. The second `bitcoind` is running on 18332/18333, right?
- You're running the latest version and you downloaded it from an official source.

Can you tell which process owns the port 80 listener? It's only listening for IPv6 connections on port 80. I think there's a `netstat` option to show the owning PID as well as process name.